# Which of the following files are true orphan (lost) files and can be safely removed?

Tags: files, package-management

I am using a script called [lostfiles](https://github.com/graysky2/lostfiles) to list all orphaned (lost) files which do not belong to any package on my Arch Linux system.

Whilst for most files I am fairly sure that I can safely delete them or at least know where they come from, for the following files I am not sure if it is safe to remove them.

```
# It is not maintained by any package but can I safely delete it?
/core 

# still used by gtk2?
/etc/gtk-2.0/gdk-pixbuf.loaders 

/etc/pango/pango.modules
/etc/pango/pango.modules-32

/etc/.pwd.lock

# Not owned by udev?
/etc/udev/hwdb.bin 

/etc/xdg/gtk-2.0

/etc/xml/catalog

# not owned by ruby?
/usr/bin/update_rubygems 

# Can I safely delete these cache files?
/usr/lib32/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache
/usr/lib32/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules.cache
/usr/lib32/libffi-3.0.12
/usr/lib32/libffi-3.0.12/include
/usr/lib32/libffi-3.0.12/include/ffi.h
/usr/lib32/libffi-3.0.12/include/ffitarget.h
/usr/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache
/usr/lib/gio/modules/giomodule.cache
/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules.cache
/usr/lib/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodules.cache

# Generated by locale-gen?
/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive

# I can safely remove the cache file?
/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache

/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/gschemas.compiled
/usr/share/gtk-doc/html/gtk2/AbstractObje....html

/usr/share/info/dir
/usr/share/libgphoto2
/usr/share/libgphoto2/asus_oled.ko.gz

# Am I safe to delete the timestamp history?
/var/db/sudo/orschiro
/var/db/sudo/orschiro/0
/var/db/sudo/orschiro/1
/var/db/sudo/orschiro/2
/var/db/sudo/orschiro/3
/var/db/sudo/orschiro/4
/var/db/sudo/orschiro/5
/var/db/sudo/orschiro/6
/var/db/sudo/orschiro/7
/var/db/sudo/orschiro/8
/var/db/sudo/orschiro/pid12778
/var/db/sudo/orschiro/pid14461
/var/db/sudo/orschiro/tty1
/var/db/sudo/orschiro/tty2
/var/db/sudo/orschiro/tty4
/var/db/sudo/test
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to say no, don't erase *most* of those.  Some of them I believe are part of a package -- you haven't said how you determined this.

Some of them may have been left over from a removed package; this can happen if, e.g., a configuration file was changed, or there is some reason to believe something else might use it.  Some of them probably fall into this category and are just empty directories.  In any case, these are infinitesimal things and they are not worth worrying about.

I see two possible reasons for doing what you are doing:

- **You want to keep your filesystem tidy and save space/inodes.**

Unless you are dealing with an embedded system where every byte counts or something, what you are doing will be irrelevant.  And if you are dealing with such a system, this would be a very very poor and ineffectual method of trying to  save space.

- **You are paranoid about unknown files.**

This is a better reason, but still bound to be ineffectual; there's no way you are going to track stuff this way, and a half-savvy intruder can simply replace files that do belong if s/he needs storage.  If you want to watch for intrusion in terms of changes to the filesystem, you need something that actually monitors it or scans it intermittently -- not an eyeball list.  There is simply too much to track for a person to do this effectively.  You are far better off using your time learning to use an automated system designed for this purpose.

That said, there are a few things I believe are safe to remove:

```
# It is not maintained by any package but can I safely delete it?
/core
```

If this is a big fat binary file that hasn't been touched recently (as in, since your last boot), then yes.  `core` files are debugging dumps sometimes left behind by applications that have crashed.

```
# Am I safe to delete the timestamp history?
```

Things like logs that obviously have not been accessed in a while (i.e., *old* logs) are probably safe to remove.  Just in case, I would move these somewhere for a while -- to a `/trash` directory -- before actually deleting them.  If you copy the whole path into the trash directory, it is easy to restore them if need be.

Comment: I have determined this through the use of lostfiles script: https://github.com/graysky2/lostfiles . Regarding my motivation, it is probably a mixture of both. Not really a necessity of space but the desire to understand what files end up as orphans and why they end up there. Mostly because I always assumed that Linux's package management is very effective and doesn't leave any orphans at all.

Comment: Interesting.  I'd err on the side of caution and only delete things you know are safe to delete -- of course  determining that is the point of your question, but keep in mind that makes the question extremely broad.  So, e.g., if you really really want to know what the purpose of `/etc/gtk-2.0/gdk-pixbuf.loaders` might be, you'll probably have to do a bit of research and ask about that specifically.

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely do so and try to come up with a comprehensive list of orphaned files which are save to be deleted and why they are save to be deleted. Once I have this list, I will post it here.

Comment: I further cleaned up my lost files by doing the following. 1. I first looked into each of the relevant packages provided by my Linux distribution if they still expect one of the given files above. Example: https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/gdk-pixbuf/ 2. I first moved the lost file to `<file>.bak`, rebooted and looked how the system behaves and if any errors are produced. If not, I deleted the file completely.

Answer (score 1):

/core is a crash dump, safe to remove http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump

The rest, I don't know . .

Answer (score 0):

To take `core`-files...  These are made when a program crashes.  The OS basically takes what's in the memory belonging to the process that crashes, and writes it to a file.  `core`-files can be very useful for developers, since a debugger can be used to analyze it.  But for normal users using pre-packed binaries stripped of the extra stuff needed for effective debugging (ie. for most of us), `core`-files just takes up much space and can be safely deleted.  In fact, running `find` regularely to find and delete old `core`-files, may be a good idea (an excellent use of `cron`).  `core`-files are usually created in the directory a program is "run from", so they're usually in user's home-directories.

The odd core-file isn't much of a problem, but if the same program always crashed and/or creates core-files, may show a more serious problem (core-files may be created by sub-processess and such that crashes too, so the main program may continue to run even if a core-file was created).  It's possible to limit the size of or turn off creation of core-files, which most distros do for normal users.  (Think it can be done with the `ulimit` command...)

The fact that this `core`-file lays directly under root, shows that it's some sort of program ran by the root-user that crashed.  It may be a good idea to look at it first, to see if you can find out what program it was (`less` should be enough...  It's binary gibberish, but usually you'll be able to spot the program's name in the mess), and then check if it's misbehaving regularely.